# wso2 ESB server keeps logging out

Tags: wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have installed wso2 ESB server and DSS server started up in the same machine. (Win 7, 32 bit). I start the ESB server and then the DSS server via command prompts and I'm able to access both admin consoles. But when I try to work on the ESB admin console (like trying to create a new proxy service, sequence) the ESB keeps on logging out and I have to login again. But I can work on DSS console without any issues. Kindly share if anyone have any insights on this behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this is a known bug.

The only workaround I know is to use two different browsers (eg: Chrome & Firefox) or use an anonymous Window for one of the consoles.

Comment: that helped, Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before , try clearing your browser cache/passwords , then restart the server if possible.